# Unable to get screen width & height in surface holder in android?

Tags: android

i am new to android and stuck with getting screen size. Here is my code,

```
package com.piyush.droidz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import com.piyush.droidz.model.boy;

public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private GameThread td;
private boy b1;
private int s_width;
private int s_height;

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Screen width=" + s_width);
    b1 = new boy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boy), 50, 50);
    td = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    s_width = getHolder().getSurfaceFrame().width();
    Log.d(TAG, "Present Screen width=" + s_width);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    td.setRunning(true);
    td.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    td.setRunning(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        b1.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

        if (event.getY()>getHeight()-50) {
            td.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Coordinates: X="+event.getX()+", Y="+event.getY());
        }
    }

    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (b1.isTouched()) {
            b1.setX((int)event.getX());
            b1.setY((int)event.getY());
        }
    }

    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        b1.setTouched(false);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    b1.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

in the first log-tag it shows 0 where as in the second log-tag it shows exact width of emulator. I have tried initializing the "s_width" with `getHolder().getSurfaceFrame().width()` even before the constructor but still "s_width" is 0. Also tried `WindowManager`and `getwindowManager()` but it is not recognized by IDE in this class. Here is my Activity class,

```
package com.piyush.droidz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class DroidzActivity extends Activity {

MainGamePanel mgp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mgp = new MainGamePanel(this);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(mgp);
}

}
```

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

You need to use context for getting the WindowManager. please see the documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html

Preferably the above should be done inside the constructor

```
public MainGamePanel(Context context) {}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thanks a lot dude it worked for me just got the widthPixels from metrics. At last one more help just for info will it work for API 13 and above. Well it is working on API 17 already on my emulator.